GitHub pull request template for custom folder
I would like to apply a pull request template whenever certain folder is changed.
Based on what was written in the documentation, I assumed that it is possible.
They mentioned only docs folder, but I was thinking that I can use any other folder as well.
So, can I use any folder the same way as "docs" or "docs" is the only folder that supports this?

The documentation you've linked tells you exactly which directories you can put the template in, and does not only mention docs/.

I mean the folder which I can apply special template for. Other locations will just apply the template for all pull requests.

A PR template in docs/ doesn't only get used for PRs that change files exclusively in docs/. All of the valid locations are for templates for all PRs.
